# Prove that a surjective homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}^3$ to itself is isomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, free-abelian-group

I am trying to prove theat a surjective homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}^3$ to itself is actually an isomorphism. The question was given after the material of free abelian groups was taught.

I actually do not have any idea of how to start reachinig this problem, and would very like your hints/help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: What does the first isomorphism theorem (i.e if $\varphi: G \to H$ is a homomorphism, then $G/\operatorname{ker}(\varphi) \to \operatorname{im}(\varphi)$ is an isomorphism) tell you about the kernel of such a map, can it be non-trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the **rank** of a free abelian group? It is defined as the size of a maximal linearly-independent set, and generalizes the notion of dimension of a vector space.

If $f : \mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}^3$ is surjective, then $f(e_1)$, $f(e_2)$, $f(e_3)$ must form a spanning set of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ (here $\{e_i\}$ is the standard basis). But since 3 is the minimal size of a spanning set of $\mathbb{Z}^3$, this set must actually be a basis. Thus it is linearly independent, and $f$ is injective.

---

If you aren't familiar with this machinery, you can instead argue that 
$f(x) = e_1$, $f(y) = e_2$, and $f(z) = e_3$ for some $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}^3$, since $f$ is surjective. But this information is exactly what we need to define a homomorphism $g : \mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}^3$ where $g(e_1) = x$, $g(e_2) = y$, $g(e_3) = z$. Can you see why this is an inverse to $f$, and thus $f$ was an isomorphism all along?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you very much!
I think I get the first argument - we can take, say $y \in \mathbb{Z}^3$, so $f^{-1}(y) $ exists because f is surjective, and then $f^{-1}(y) = a * e_1 + b*e_2 + c*e_3$. Therefore, $y = f(f^{-1}(y)) = a*f(e_1)+b*f(e_2)+c*f(e_3)$. In addition, it is injective becuase of, saying kernel argument. Taking $x \in Ker(f)$  $s.t.$ $s \not= e$, then looking at $f(x)$.

However, I am not sure I fully understood the second argument. Why is the information about $f(x), f(y), f(z)$ is enough to define $g(x)$ and for it to be well-defined?

Thank you very much again!

Comment: Any homomorphism out of $\mathbb{Z}$ is completely determined by where it sends $1$. This is because, if $f(1) = x$, then $f(4) = f(1+1+1+1) = x+x+x+x$. Indeed, there's nothing special about $4$ - once you know $f(1)$, you know $f(n)$. Moreover, there's no restriction on what $f(1)$ can be. So homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to G$ are in bijective correpsondence with elements of $G$. (Continued in the next comment)

Comment: Similarly, homomorphisms out of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ are completely determined by the images of the three generators. We know they all commute, so the image had better be abelian, but other than that, we can choose any three elements in our target group at all! Why? Because if we know $f(1,0,0)$, $f(0,1,0)$, and $f(0,0,1)$, then we know $f(x,y,z)$ because it's $x f(1,0,0) + y f(0,1,0) + z f(0,0,1)$ (where by multiplication I really mean repeated addition). This marks $\mathbb{Z}^3$ as the Free Abelian Group with 3 Generators, and is known as a "universal property". It's definitely worth knowing!

Comment: Thank you a lot! (: